# JavaFX tableview not displaying properly

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a JavaFX application with a scene with two tableviews, the first one works correctly, the second one doesn't.

The second tableview only displays the content of 2 out of the 5 columns it should, and the content on the second column, should be actually on the last column. I have used javaFX a few times before and it's the first time I see something like this, I revised my code 2 or 3 times looking for things that could be wrong or mispelled, but I haven't been able to find it.

This is what the tableview displays.

[image]

This is the code of the object class it contains.

```
public class Producte {

    private int codi;
    private String nom;
    private String descripcio;
    private float preu;
    private int codiFabricant;

    public Producte(String nom, String descripcio, float preu,
            int codiFabricant) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.descripcio = descripcio;
        this.preu = preu;
        this.codiFabricant = codiFabricant;
    }

    public Producte(int codi, String nom, String descripcio, float preu,
            int codiFabricant) {
        this.codi = codi;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.descripcio = descripcio;
        this.preu = preu;
        this.codiFabricant = codiFabricant;
    }

    public int getCodi() {
        return codi;
    }

    public void setCodi(int codi) {
        this.codi = codi;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getDescripcio() {
        return descripcio;
    }

    public void setDescripcio(String descripcio) {
        this.descripcio = descripcio;
    }

    public float getPreu() {
        return preu;
    }

    public void setPreu(float preu) {
        this.preu = preu;
    }

    public int getCodiFabricant() {
        return codiFabricant;
    }

    public void setCodiFabricant(int codiFabricant) {
        this.codiFabricant = codiFabricant;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Producte [codi=" + codi + ", nom=" + nom + ", descripcio="
                + descripcio + ", preu=" + preu + ", codiFabricant="
                + codiFabricant + "]";
    }

}
```

And this is the code from the method that loads the scene.
The first tableview is the dirTable, the second one(the one that doesn't work properly is the prodTable). Thanks in advance for any help :/

```
static Scene directorScene() {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gridPane.setVgap(25);
        gridPane.setHgap(25);

        director = DirectorFunctions.director;

        final ObservableList<Director> dirList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        dirList.add(director);

        TableView<Director> dirTable = new TableView<>();
        dirTable.setItems(dirList);

        TableColumn<Director, String> fabCol = new TableColumn<>("Fabricant");
        TableColumn<Director, String> dniCol = new TableColumn<>("DNI");
        TableColumn<Director, String> nomCol = new TableColumn<>("Nom");
        TableColumn<Director, String> mailCol = new TableColumn<>("Mail");
        TableColumn<Director, String> passCol = new TableColumn<>("Pass");

        fabCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Director,String>("Nom"));
        dniCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Director,String>("DniDirector"));
        nomCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Director,String>("NomDirector"));
        mailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Director,String>("MailDirector"));
        passCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Director,String>("PasswordDirector"));

        dirTable.getColumns().setAll(fabCol, dniCol, nomCol, mailCol, passCol);
        dirTable.setMinWidth(450);
        dirTable.setMaxHeight(52);
        dirTable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

        gridPane.add(dirTable, 0, 0);

        Button modificarDirector = new Button("Modificar");
        modificarDirector.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        gridPane.add(modificarDirector, 1, 0);

        final ObservableList<Producte> prodList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (Producte p:DirectorFunctions.productes.values()) {
            prodList.add(p);
        }

        TableView<Producte> prodTable = new TableView<>();
        prodTable.setItems(prodList);

        TableColumn<Producte, String> codiPCol = new TableColumn<>("Codi");
        TableColumn<Producte, String> nomPCol = new TableColumn<>("Nom");
        TableColumn<Producte, String> descPCol = new TableColumn<>("Descripció");
        TableColumn<Producte, String> preuPCol = new TableColumn<>("Preu");
        TableColumn<Producte, String> fabPCol = new TableColumn<>("Fabricant");

        codiPCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producte, String>("Codi"));
        nomPCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producte, String>("Nom"));
        nomPCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producte, String>("Descripcio"));
        nomPCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producte, String>("Preu"));
        nomPCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producte, String>("CodiFabricant"));

        prodTable.getColumns().setAll(codiPCol, nomPCol, descPCol, preuPCol, fabPCol);
        prodTable.setMinWidth(450);
        prodTable.setMaxHeight(200);
        prodTable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

        gridPane.add(prodTable, 0, 1);

        Button nouButton = new Button("Nou");
        nouButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        nouButton.setMinWidth(75);

        Button modButton = new Button("Modificar");
        modButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        modButton.setMinWidth(75);

        Button delButton = new Button("Borrar");
        delButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        delButton.setMinWidth(75);

        Button backButton = new Button("Tornar");
        backButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        backButton.setMinWidth(75);
        gridPane.add(backButton, 1, 2);

        VBox vbox = new VBox(25);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(nouButton, modButton, delButton);
        gridPane.add(vbox, 1, 1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 640, 480, Color.web("eee"));
        return scene;
    }
```

This is the Director class for whoever wants to see it as well

```
public class Director {

    private int codi;
    private String nom;
    private String dniDirector;
    private String nomDirector;
    private String mailDirector;
    private String passwordDirector;

    public Director(int codi, String nom, String dniDirector,
            String nomDirector, String mailDirector, String passwordDirector) {
        this.codi = codi;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.dniDirector = dniDirector;
        this.nomDirector = nomDirector;
        this.mailDirector = mailDirector;
        this.passwordDirector = passwordDirector;
    }

    public int getCodi() {
        return codi;
    }

    public void setCodi(int codi) {
        this.codi = codi;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getDniDirector() {
        return dniDirector;
    }

    public void setDniDirector(String dniDirector) {
        this.dniDirector = dniDirector;
    }

    public String getNomDirector() {
        return nomDirector;
    }

    public void setNomDirector(String nomDirector) {
        this.nomDirector = nomDirector;
    }

    public String getMailDirector() {
        return mailDirector;
    }

    public void setMailDirector(String mailDirector) {
        this.mailDirector = mailDirector;
    }

    public String getPasswordDirector() {
        return passwordDirector;
    }

    public void setPasswordDirector(String passwordDirector) {
        this.passwordDirector = passwordDirector;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fabricant [codi=" + codi + ", nom=" + nom + ", dniDirector="
                + dniDirector + ", nomDirector=" + nomDirector
                + ", mailDirector=" + mailDirector + ", passwordDirector="
                + passwordDirector + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the Director Class

Comment: yeah, I'll edit it in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to use JavaFX Property for all your model. You can find samples in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm).

[`PropertyValueFactory<S,T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) looks for a property of type `T` in `S` with the same name that you typed in the constructor.

For example, in a model class `Product` which has a StringProperty field `name`,

```
new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("name")
```

will look for :

```
nameProperty()
```

and if it doesn't find it, it will further look for `getName()` and wrap it in a  `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` before returning it.

From the docs,

> If no method matching this pattern exists, there is fall-through
>   support for attempting to call get() or is() (that
>   is, getFirstName() or isFirstName() in the example above). If a method
>   matching this pattern exists, the value returned from this method is
>   wrapped in a ReadOnlyObjectWrapper and returned to the TableCell

The problem in your example is that your table column has a cellValueFactory which says,

```
nomPCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producte, String>("Preu"));
```

but your getter method is returning a `float` instead of a `String`

```
public float getPreu() {
    return preu;
}
```

Comment: And yeah, I will fix it, and I'll try to not do it like that again, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem already, I used copy+paste to duplicate lines of the code and I forgot to change the name on the columns for the table. I'm an idiot -__-.

Sorry for wasting your time guys...

By the way, is there a way to close a thread/question without having to ask mods or something?